# Sharepoint Post-Upgrade Permissions Issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, wss-3.0, ribbon, upgrade

I recently Migrated web front end and database server of wss 3.0 single farm to sp2010 foundation. Farm Migration and upgrade went well, Then i restored content db from older server and upgraded the db. That went well too. After activating all the features and services, i had some issues with Fab40  templates, which also got resolved.

After all of that now i am stuck with new issue, MY ribbon control of Site collection says, i dont have enough permission to perform certain task. Also ribbon bar always defaults to view tab with all greyed out.

I checked the database, All the permissions are good, database not set to read only. Checked updated site collection admin of the web-application. Still i dont have all the permissions since i have all the rights.

[image]

I dont know how to trouble shoot this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you're using a custom master page on this site. Try resetting to SharePoint's default, or upload a fresh one from a site that works, and see if that helps.

Comment: Right On!! David. It was my stupid css that was causing that. I will rework my css and hope to get it fixed. Thank you for your help. Also about permissions, i re-restored backup of the old farm to new web application, it looks like that fixed the issue, i am waiting for response from customer.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help